# How to convert JavaScript library into to npm module?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to node js and i wanted to convert some of external library
 into NPM module please do help

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't modify any external library, but let assume that you go to `node_modules` and modified some code when you'll run `npm install` and if there are any new version of that library then you code will be overwritten.

But let say that you have some js code

```
function greeting(name) {
  return `Hello ${name}!`
}

const user = {
    firstName: 'James',
    lastName: 'Bond'
}

// then you can export this function like this
module.export = greeting;

module.exports = user ;



// Other way to export a function greetings.js
sayHelloInEnglish = function() {
  return "Hello";
};

module.export = sayHelloInEnglish;
```

You can also rename named exports to avoid naming conflicts:

```
export { myFunction as function1,
         myVariable as variable };
```

You can read more here or if you have any any question feel free to ask.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/javascript-modules-for-beginners-56939088f7d9

Comment: thanks for your reply but my question is for ex : if i wanted to convert jquery library into npm module ?? then how can i???

Comment: Lot of libraries already 'inside' node package manager, for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery, and if you want something to do probability is high that someone already did this and in npm is already a package that will do your needs there is no need to reinvent the wheel or if you anyways want to creade a new package check this links
https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules
https://medium.com/the-andela-way/build-and-publish-your-first-npm-package-a4daf0e2431
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-a-beautiful-tiny-npm-package-and-publish-it-2881d4307f78/

Comment: what if the library doesn't exists in the npm registry  then i will have to convert js library to npm module n publish to the registry for later use , please do help me

Comment: yes you have to convert it to `npm module`, but usually this stuff are done by people or team with lot of experience. How I said previously almost for everything there are packages in npm.